# glDebugMessageControl is not available

Tags: opengl, graphics, jogl, pyopengl

I'm currently playing around with OpenGL using JOGL and PyOpenGL on my MacBook Pro.

But very quickly I came to the point where a lot of example codes crash, because the address of `glDebugMessageControl` is not available. First I experienced the error using JOGL in Eclipse running [this code](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/hello-triangle/blob/master/src/main/java/gl4/HelloTriangleSimple.java).

But now i tried to invoke the same function with Python and I got the same error. 
So guess it is probably hardware related.

Why does OpenGL have no access to the "glDebugMessageController"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glDebugMessageControl` is an OpenGL 4.3 function, also exposed through the [KHR_debug core extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/KHR/KHR_debug.txt). You **must not** call the function pointer for it unless you verified that the version of your GL context is at least 4.3, or `KHR_debug` is listed as available extension. If that is not the case, it would even be undefined behavior to call the function pointer even if it were not `NULL`.

> But now i tried to invoke the same function with Python and I got the same error. So guess it is probably hardware related.

It's Apple-related. Apple stopped supporting OpenGL in favor of their own [*Metal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_%28API%29) graphics API, so OpenGL is stuck in a state from years ago on OSX. It doesn't support debug callbacks at all.

Comment: Apple OpenGL versions [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202823).

Comment: Alright, thank you so much. I should probably install Windows or Linux on my Mac then, if I want to use the state-of-the-art OpenGL... :-/